# What would be a hardy evergreen flowering vine that can live in Southern Ontario (5b)

Tags: vines, flowering, evergreens

What would be a hardy evergreen flowering vine that can live in Southern Ontario (5b)

Here is the map
http://www.plantmaps.com/interactive-ontario-plant-zone-hardiness-map.php

Comment: few, if any, evergreen vines in Ontario.  There are pretenders like euonymus fortunei but one bad winter and it's not evergreen any more.  Do you have to have evergreen?

Comment: At least some kinds of holly are said to be able to grow as vines or climbers. Also, some kinds of holly are hardy to hardiness zone 3. They are more known for their ornamental berries than the flowers, though, but they do get flowers. Holly is evergreen.

Comment: Skip the evergreen part and clematis does well.

Comment: Thanks Ecnerwall, I think that I will go with trumpet vines

Answer (score 1):

Evergreen,flowering, climbing in Zone 5b - there isn't one I'm afraid. There isn't one that does that in the UK, and we're Zone 8, mostly, so I'm afraid it comes down to a choice between an evergreen shrub, or an evergreen climber like Hedera helix (Ivy) or a deciduous flowering climber.

If you decide you can tolerate a non-evergreen flowering climber, Campsis radicans is fully hardy in your zone, but note it flowers much better in a very sunny spot I think this plant is commonly known as Trumpet vine where you are.

http://www.canadaplants.ca/display.php?id=307

Comment: Campsis radicans is not evergreen in Ontario 5b.  You might get a mild winter where the leaves hang on but drop off in the spring.  That's the way my evergreen Mahonia behaves in zone 5a.

Comment: @kevinsky - erm, you might wanna read my answer again - it does say clearly  that its deciduous... given there isn't any flowering vine thats evergreen that will survive

Comment: sorry, I found your sentence confusing and interpreted campsis as your answer to the original evergreen question

Comment: no worries - except I'm wondering now why its confusing - I shall have another look at it...

Comment: @kevinsky - can you clarify something for me please? whenpeople in your part of the world use the word 'vine', what precisely does it mean? Its just that in Europe snd UK 'vine' refers primariy to Parthenocissus, but may also be used for any climbing plant - I've seen the term vine used on here sometimes when the person seems to be speaking of a non climbing plant, so does it specifically mean 'climber' there, or just any plant? Same query with the word 'herb' which I've seen used on here for any old plant apparently

Comment: @kevinsky - I don't mean psrthenocissus, I mean Vitis generally.... those are vines, everything else like campsis is a climber, plants thast don' climb but are freestanding are trees or shrubs... not so there?

Comment: In North America common usage for a vine is a plant grows up something else with or without sticky pads.  Or a sprawling vine.  So it includes Vitus, clematis, climbing roses, kudzu and so on.  This may be why gardening is not a science if common terms cannot be defined easily

Comment: Thanks. You have at least confirmed that North America uses 'vine' for plants which climb, so our 'climbers' are your 'vines' - I've seen the term used on here for coniferous trees. Guess it all depends where you live what terms you use. Churchill's comment 'USA and GB, two countries divided by a  common language' is a neat observation!

Comment: And folks who grow Humulus Lupus (hops) are prone to make the distinction that it's a bine, while those who don't try to call them vines as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal bit purist, but botanically that's right - also makes runner beans (think you might call them pole beans over there) bines... and clematis are vines. I just differentiate by calling climbers twiners or petiole climbers, since bine/vine thing is a bit obscure